# How do I unload content from the content manager?

Tags: xna, content-management

I tried using the dispose function on a texture2d but that caused problems and I'm pretty sure it's not what I'm meant to use.

What should I use to basically unload content? Does the content manager keep track itself or is there something I have to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does XNAs Content.Load<Texture2D> operate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242741/how-does-xnas-content-loadtexture2d-operate)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242741/how-does-xnas-content-loadtexture2d-operate/4242832#4242832) and possibly [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5615/disposing-only-certain-resources-in-xna/).

The `ContentManager` "owns" all the content that it loads and is responsible for unloading it. The only way you should unload content that a ContentManager has loaded is by using `ContentManager.Unload()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.contentmanager.unload.aspx)).

If you are not happy with this default behaviour of ContentManager, you can replace it as described in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/09/contentmanager-readasset.aspx).

Any textures or other unload-able resources that you create yourself *without* going through `ContentManager` should be disposed (by calling `Dispose()`) in your `Game.UnloadContent` function.

Comment: There is also a ContentManager.Unload(bool disposing) which is described as also unloading managed content if true. Are there xna content types in the xna library that are managed and need manual disposing?

Comment: @Wouter Unload doesn't take an argument in any version I see on MSDN. You might be looking at `Dispose(bool disposing)` (which is a protected method, can't call externally). This is part of the standard C# disposable pattern ([explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)). `Dispose(true)` gets called during standard disposal (the `using` statement or directly calling `Dispose()`) and will itself call `Unload()`. `Dispose(false)` gets called by the finalizer and specifically does not call `Unload` (it can't access other objects, they might have already been finalized).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dispose a texture, the easiest way to do it:

```
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D texture;
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\Brick00");
    }
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Logic which disposes texture, it may be different.
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            texture.Dispose();
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise, null);

        // Here you should check, was it disposed.
        if (!texture.IsDisposed)
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(resolution.Width / 2, resolution.Height / 2), null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 0.25f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

If you want to dispose all content after exiting the game, the best way to do it:

```
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        Content.Unload();
    }
```

If you want to dispose only texture after exiting the game:

```
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        texture.Dispose();
    }
```