# In XNA, what is the best method to dispose of textures I no longer need?

Tags: memory-management, xna, textures, out-of-memory

I started a project with the concept of reusing the same texture2d objects continuously throughout the game, reloading new textures periodically. Over time this proved a bad idea as I was running in to: System.OutOfMemoryException

```
    bool loadImages(string image)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("beginning loading textures " + image);

        try
        {
            //image_a = null;
            //image_o = null;

            //image_o.Dispose();
            //image_a.Dispose();

            image_o = Content.Load<Texture2D>("images/"+image);
            image_a = Content.Load<Texture2D>("images/" + image+"_a");


            return true;
        }
        catch 
        { 
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("cannot load textures " + image);         
            image_a.Dispose(); 
            image_o.Dispose(); 
        }

        return false; //make sure the caller loads the subsequent image
    }
```

I guessed that XNA was holding on to the past textures with each new content load, so I rewrote the program to instead hold a list of game objects each with its own texture2d objects. Upon going through the list I would dispose of the previous list item's texture objects and load the next list item's textures to its texture objects. The list would only be traversed once over the entire game, just periodically would I move on to the next texture set, and I would only pick out 2 textures to load so in theory there should only ever be needed 2 textures in memory at all times. I still ran in to a memory error. It's as if I can't at all rely on the dispose method to release textures from memory in a timely manner.

None of the textures I'm loading is over 125KB, I'm building this for windows phone 7

What is the best method to drop the textures I no longer need? Referring to the code: should I instead create new texture2d objects, swap them, and dispose of the originals?

Comment: This may be far too late for your purposes, but contenttracker.codeplex.com is able to unload individual content items, and it also handles the complex issue of internal references between content items such as Model -> Texture(s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, first a bit of background: **`ContentManager` caches loaded objects.** There's a more detailed description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265786/165500) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9870420/165500)). But basically each `ContentManager` *owns* everything it loads. You should not call `Dispose` on that content. The only way to clean it up is to unload everything in the cache with `ContentManager.Unload` (or `Dispose`).

I'm guessing that the issue you're having is that you've tried to `Load` a texture that you've previously called `Dispose` on - and are then attempting to use that disposed texture.

Although I suppose you could also run out of memory because the `ContentManager` is storing all those (empty, disposed) `Texture2D` objects, preventing the garbage collector from reclaiming them (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3433209/165500)).

So, if you want to go down this route, you need to modify the caching policy of `ContentManager`. How to do this is explained in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/09/contentmanager-readasset.aspx). But basically you inherit from `ContentManager`, override `Load`, and call `ReadAsset` when you want to create a new instance of an asset from a content file.

The simplest thing to do would be to disable caching entirely, and that blog post has an example of exactly that. Then you can simply manually manage the lifetime of everything that content manager loads (i.e.: call `Dispose` on it yourself).

If you want something a bit more sophisticated, perhaps look at the design I propose in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33088/texture-caching-in-2d-xna-game), over on the GameDev site.

Comment: as I load content and then load new content to the same texture2d object, the previous content is still in cache-- correct? i'll have to read up on when content manager decides that old cached texture is no longer useful, if ever. recreating a content manager seems like a very non-trivial way to solve a trivial issue. thanks for the info, time for me to read :)

Comment: Yes, you'll receive a reference to the cached instance when loading the same asset multiple times by the same ContentManager.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought I could find an easy way out using the unload and load content methods, sadly I still find myself in the same predicament and it appears I'll have to extend the content manager like you said.

Comment: Thank you for your posts, I was about to screw up my program!!

Comment: are you saying that I don't have to call Dispose() on objects I no longer use?

Comment: @Kokodoko The short answer is: *someone* has to call `Dispose()` on (disposable) objects once they are no longer in use. There are cases, such as with objects from `ContentManager.Load`, where someone *else* will call `Dispose()` for you.